# Underscore.js throttle not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, throttling

### Objective

Figure what is wrong with my code, or if underscore.js throttle works as it should.

### Background

I have a huge list of postal codes in a file, and I am reading those codes and pasting them on console.

I am trying to use [Underscore.js throttle() function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle), however my code stops after two runs (even though I have dozens), and the rest of the values are never printed.

### Code

My code is in a very simple NodeJS project. I created a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the situation I am facing:

```
"use strict";

//requiremetns
let fs = require('fs');
let readLine = require('readline');
let _ = require('underscore');

//constants
const INPUT_FILE = 'dataset.txt';
const RADIX_CONVERSATION = 10;
const THROTTLE_DELAY = 500;

let init = function() {

  let lineReader = readLine.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(INPUT_FILE),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
  });

  let throttledRequestFn = _.throttle(requestFn, THROTTLE_DELAY);

  lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    line = line.trim();

    if (_.isNaN(parseInt(line, RADIX_CONVERSATION))) {
      //Do some stuff
    }
    else {
      throttledRequestFn('mahCountry', line);
    }
  });
};

let requestFn = function(country, postalCode){
  console.log('request for ' + country + ' and postal ' + postalCode + ' done');
  return false;
};


init();
```

Here I first start by reading the file, one line at a time. Then if the line I am reading is a number, I print something, otherwise nothing.

Following is a test file:

```
Vietnam
000000  
100000
160000  
170000  
180000  
200000
220000
230000
240000  
250000  
260000
270000
280000
290000  
300000  
310000  
320000  
330000
350000
360000
380000
390000
400000  
410000  
420000
430000  
440000
460000  
480000
510000
520000
530000
550000
560000
570000  
580000  
590000
600000
620000
630000
640000  
650000  
660000
670000
700000
790000  
800000
810000  
820000
830000
840000  
850000
860000  
870000  
880000  
890000  
900000
910000
920000
930000  
940000
950000
960000
970000
```

### Question

The way I see it, my code should make 2 requests per second, with a 500 ms of delay between each one. It should print all the codes in the test file.
However, I never seen anything past the second value! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `throttle` function is working as intended. From the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle):

> Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

This means that your wrapped function will probably be called *less often* than you want.

What you actually want is probably some kind of queue. Underscore doesn't provide one, but the async library does: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue

```
let fs = require('fs');
let readLine = require('readline');
let _ = require('async');
// import the async library
let async = require('async');

const INPUT_FILE = 'dataset.txt';
const RADIX_CONVERSATION = 10;

// create the queue
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
  // make sure the queue task calls the callback only after the THROTTLE_DELAY
  setTimeout(function () {
    requestFn(task.country, task.postalCode);
    callback();
  }, THROTTLE_DELAY);

}, 1)

q.drain = function () {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
};

let init = function () {
  let lineReader = readLine.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(INPUT_FILE),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
  });

  lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    line = line.trim();

    if (_.isNaN(parseInt(line, RADIX_CONVERSATION))) {
      // Do some stuff
    }
    else {
      // Add the line to the Queue, to be executed later
      q.push({country: 'mahCountry', postalCode: line});
    }
  });
};

let requestFn = function(country, postalCode){
  console.log('request for ' + country + ' and postal ' + postalCode + ' done');
  return false;
};

init();
```

Notice the use of `setTimeout` in the function that handles the elements in the queue. That way, you'll still only make one request every 500ms, but will be guaranteed to make all of them.

Comment: How does it work as intended? I have like 40 postal codes but I only see it being called 2 times :S I am missing something? Should it not call the function every 500 ms ? This is what I got from the documentation.

Comment: It works as the developer of Underscore intended. `throttle` doesn't queue your function calls to execute them later, it just ignores them until your throttle delay is over, and then executes *only one*, at which point it starts to ignore the calls again. As I said: You probably want to use a queue.

Comment: So, I can use a queue together with underscore.js throttle ?

Comment: You don't have to use throttle at all. I'll provide an example, hold on.

Comment: Wait! I really appreciate your pro-activeness, however since I am query an external API and I have limited QPS, I need to throttle my requests (in this case, I need to throttle my calls to requestFn) ! This is why underscore.js `throttle` looked so promising in the first place =(

Also, kudos++ for the attitude !

Comment: I added an example! It does throttle the calls, so you should be fine! But it also makes sure to handle all of the elements. Try it out!

Comment: I found a solution using _.delay, but since you had all the trouble, I will accept your asnwer!